# This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY: This case is parented by a case that is also its child

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow

I am getting the error while updating the case parent ID with the same case ID.

Thank you

Comment: Hello, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. This community is about providing solutions to specific technical problems. The error is explained by itself - you cannot make the record a parent of itself. What do you want to achieve here?

Answer (score 1):

By design, the structure has to be a tree where as you navigate up the parent references you eventually get to a single root object that has no parent. The design does not support the situation where there is a never-ending "circle" of references including when there is only a single item referencing itself.